# Is there a solution for periodically commit in tortoisehg/mercurial ?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I am using tortoisehg. I would like it to find changes and commit them periodically.
I couldn't find useful anything for tortoisehg, I found one thing,

http://josh-in-antarctica.blogspot.com.tr/2008/03/automatic-change-tracking-with-cron-and.html

But I didn't understood how I can use it,

Also there is a tool for git, you can see it [here](http://lifehacker.com/5232049/flashbake-automates-version-control-for-nerdy-writers).

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Perhaps a filesystem with snapshotting would appeal to you?

Comment: I am working with bitbucket, Sometimes I can forget to commit my files or I can update it to previous version inadvertently. So I lose recent files. If the commit can be done specific intervals, thus I can prevent them.

Comment: I think most people just learn to do commits early and often, whenever finishing one chunk of work.  That way the commits are more valuable than just "these are the changes when the clock hit 13:00" etc.

Comment: You're right, I am working on my project alone in my home computer. I try to do my commits properly and in time. But I can forget them that I am working alone for.

Answer (score 0):

I answered this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22092551/distributed-source-control-management-tool-mercurial question, it will give you a simple way to do this, adapt it to the *commit* command.